# Procedual textures/masks: Is it possible to get a sharp edge from bevel node result?

Tags: materials, edges, bevel, procedural, masking

I am trying to procedurally mask all edges of any kind of mesh with a sharp edged line in blender.

**Using pointiness** from the geometry node for that task has **two main disadvantages** for me:

**First**, I want to be able to generate that mask on low poly meshes without having to bake the mask from high poly versions of those meshes.
**Second**, in my tests, I was not able to mask sharp corners between two edges. In the end, pointiness is not really intended for that purpose.

Now for my question:

I know, the bevel node is supposed to "mimic" round corners, hence the falloff towards the middle of the normal, right?
**Does anyone know a way to get a sharp edge from the bevel node result?**
OR does anyone know ANY OTHER WAY to have all edges of any kind of mesh RELIABLY masked/marked with a sharp edged line?

What I really haven't looked into is scripting. If anyone knows a scripting solution to this problem or an approach to nudge me in the right direction, please feel free to share!

What I mean by falloff (red cross) and sharp edge (green tick), is marked on the screenshot below. The shader is a rgb mix of a edge mask (bevel node result) and a voronoi texture that cuts the edge mask irregularly.

I appreciate any constructive help.

The shader as seen in the screenshot below: [image]

[image: Bevel/Voronoi Mask]

Comment: Bevel node's samples can be manually set to up to 128, and it can resolve to something pretty sharp with more samples in cycles, but it's never perfect in my experience.

Comment: @Allen Simpson I actually didn't know that you could set it up to 128 manually since the slider only allows a maximum of 16 samples.  Thanks for that tipp! I really would like to have a clean sharp edge, though.